# Operator commutes with spectral projection

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be the spectral measure to an (unbounded) self-adjoint operator $A$. Is there a sufficient and necessary condition so that for a bounded interval $I$ we have $E_I A= AE_I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The necessary and sufficient condition is that $A$ is bounded.

Indeed, the domain of $AE_I$ is the whole Hilbert space, and the domain of $E_IA$ is the domain $\mathcal D(A)$ of $A$.